# Kivy does not appear Rectangle

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

**The problem is that I have a Home screen and if I launch it, everything works correctly and the Rectangle is displayed in the background**

[home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REUQg.jpg)

**Home code:**

home.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

Window.size = (430, 930)

class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):
    pass

class HomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Press Start 2P",
                    fn_regular='./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    HomeApp().run()
```

home.kv

```
<HomeScreen@Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 20
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    source: "BACKGROUND.png"
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            Image:
                source: "boss.png"
            Button:
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
                text: 'Грати'
                background_color: (0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 1)
                size_hint: 0.9, 0.15
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
            padding: 40
            spacing: 40 
            Label: 
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.15, 'center_y': 0.5}
                size_hint: 1, 0.1
                text: 'артефакти'
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 40 
                size_hint: 1, 0.8

                MainItem1:

                MainItem2:

                MainItem3:
```

**And the problem is that when I put this screen in the main, the Rectangle disappears somewhere**
[inserted the screen and the background disappeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwDCb.jpg)

**Main code**

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

Window.size = (430, 930)

class ShopScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ItemsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Home.kv")

class WindowManager(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ShopScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ItemsScreen(name='items'))
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
        Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Press Start 2P",
                    fn_regular='./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<WindowManager>:
    MDBottomNavigation: 
        font_name: "./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf"
        panel_color: get_color_from_hex("#1B1B1B")
        text_color_active: 1, 1, 0, 1
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'shop'
            text: 'МАГАЗИН'
 
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'main'
            text: 'ГОЛОВНА' 
            HomeScreen:
        
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'items'
            text: 'ХЕЛПЕРИ'
```

I searched the entire Internet and how I understood the imitation, but what exactly I did not understand